# In Cordova how can I add the iOS platform to be built in Swift and not Objective C?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova, phonegap

When I use the following command line interface in Cordova to add the iOS platform to my project the project is always built in Objective C. Is there a way I can get it to be built in Swift? I have tried the Cordova Swift Plugin but it has not worked.

```
cordova platform add ios
```